# Facing svn issue: COPY operations are only supported at the branch level

Tags: svn, github, refactoring

I am using svn to work on a project that is hosted on GitHub, and facing a strange issue.
Whenever I rename a package and try to commit the src directory (or any directory higher than the renamed directory) I am getting a message:
"svn: COPY operations are only supported at the branch level"

Example:
I have a package `com.mydomain.projectname.some.package`. 
When I rename it to `com.mydomain.projectname.some.another.package` and try to commit, I get this message.

The project is in the master branch of the GitHub repo, I check out trunk while using svn. I tried creating an identical branch and repeating the process but still no luck. Am I missing some basic svn rules here?

Comment: just use something like xp-dev.com for ordinary subversion hosting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's limitation of (current) Github's Git-SVN bridge - you work with **Git repo** on backend anyway

Comment: @JitB - you can. After SVN migration to Mercurial is more smooth way: learn Hg, use BitBucket as code-hosting

Comment: Facing same issue, @LazyBadger do you have any reference to read more about this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround that doesn't preserve history is to copy the files to the new name, then `svn delete [oldname]` and `svn add [newname]`.

This is horrible from a shared source repository perspective, as nobody else's branches will properly merge any more if they've made their own changes to those files.  But it has the advantage of actually working, and if you're the only person working with the files in question, may be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this happen when you moved or renamed a folder or file and you did another change like added code, so, another way to workaround is:

1. Revert all changes (You can do a backup of current changes if you want).
2. Just commit the moved or renamed folder or file without another change.
3. Optionally (recover your backup if you did it) then commit again.

Summary: move/rename file/folder is not supported in group with another changes.